# Delete or in mysql nodejs

Tags: mysql

So I want to delete data from a table, but also data from another table if my condition applies.

For example, I want to delete student As data from my student table and all his disciplinary issues from my issues table if any.

I am using the command

```
            DELETE student, issues
            FROM student
            INNER JOIN issues
            ON student.studentid = issues.studentid
            WHERE student.studentid=?
```

in my node.js

However, the data from my student table is only deleted if the selected student has a disciplinary issue in my issue table. Is the a way to use the OR clause somewhere in my command to achieve my intended result?

i am using postman to test my api and the command above is inserted in my code where it connects to the mysql workbench

Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs in the sql tag

Comment: So, what are you actually trying to do?  Also nothing here is working how you described.   While the inner join does backwords make it so it will only delete a student with issue, also makes the where redundant.  Also can make some unintented consequences.

Comment: @MasonStedman sorry i wasnt clear, the command im currently using works, but it only deletes the data if the student has a disciplinary issues. If the student does not have a disciplinary issue, the record for the student is not deleted. I am trying to make it so that even if my student doesnt have a disciplinary issue, his data still gets deleted. I have also edited my question to clarify. Thank you

Comment: @Finbar Sorry if my question wasnt worded correctly, i have changed it accordingly to fit in the mysql tag. Thank you

Comment: @strikevision I was more concerned about the node.js tag as this question isnt remotely related to node.js

Comment: @Finbar yes sorry i wasnt clear i am using node js as well.

Comment: Your question includes no javascript, no need for the tag.

Comment: @Finbar okay I have removed it. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: step 1: update your database schema to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` (and read up on how to use that, _lots_ of tutorials about it on the web). Then step 2: just delete your primary record and mysql will do the rest. This is one of those things that databases have built in, but you need to tell them that you want to use it by setting up your table relations properly.

Comment: Good to hear: remember to write up an answer that explains what you had to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your database schema to use ON DELETE CASCADE (and read up on how to use that, lots of tutorials about it on the web). Then step 2: just delete your primary record and mysql will do the rest. This is one of those things that databases have built in, but you need to tell them that you want to use it by setting up your table relations properly.

Answered by Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans